# Get index of the max value per pixel in multi-channel Mat

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to have a matrix with the index of the channel with the maximum value per pixel in openCV.
E.g:

```
image[1]={1,3,2,5,6,2};
```

image[2]={4,4,1,0,1,4};

Result = {2,2,1,1,1,2};

Is there a more elegant way of doing this instead of just making a for loop and find the maximum value for each pixel "manually"?

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!

In this situation, a for loop is the best thing to do since C++ doesn't natively support vector operations.

Comment: @berak, I would like to have the index of the maximum element. So max(1,4)==2 because the element "4" belongs to the second channel.

Comment: yea, sorry. did not see the index part.

Comment: It probably is possible without a for-loop using function from the `<algorithm>` header, but a straight forward solution is probably more readable.